# css font size change not sizing correctly in smartphone view

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I have used the following css code to decrease the font size of a slider heading:

```
.swiper-slide .content h2 {
  font-size:48px;
}
```

It seems to have worked fine when viewed from a desk or laptop, but the text is over sized when viewed on a smart phone.

I am using windows 7 on a PC, wordpress CMS, responsive theme...

Comment: Please always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 0):

Using font-size in % should help you to change size relatively. But you should keep in mind line-height property.

Answer (score 0):

You could try media queries?

```
html { font-size: 62.5%; }
body { font-size: 1em;}

    @media (max-width: 300px) {
        html { font-size: 70%; }
    }

    @media (min-width: 500px) {
        html { font-size: 80%; }
    }

    @media (min-width: 700px) {
        html { font-size: 120%; }
    }

    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        html { font-size: 200%; }
}
```

Try this :) **http://jsfiddle.net/yv5eu/**

Answer (score 0):

Try this technique for better resizing of text. Than with media queries you can set different font sizes.

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem
http://css-tricks.com/theres-more-to-the-css-rem-unit-than-font-sizing/
Support: http://ahedg.es/w/rem.html